# How I can create multiple populating dropdown list in Express.js with handlebars

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

enter code hereI want to create populating dropdown list. like one dropdown will have Car types (Sport, Luxury, SUV, etc) stored in mongodb using mongoose and another dropdown will have car names like (Ferrari, Lamborghini, Rollce Royece) also stored in mongodb.  If i select car type as "sport" in one dropdown, another dropdown should show only sport cars name fetch from mongoDB using mongoose.

Express Js

```
app.get('/car', (req, res) => {
  res.render('car/');
});
```

index.handlebars

```
 <div class="row mb-3">
        <div class="col">
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
            <div class="form-group dropdown">
                <label for="Category" value=""> Select Category </label>
                <select class="form-control" id="" name="Category">
                    {{#each category}}
                    <option>{{category}}</option>
                    {{/each}}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group dropdown">
                <label for="Car" value=""> Select Car</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="" name="Car">
                    {{#each Car}}
                    <option>{{car}}</option>
                    {{/each}}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Category model.js

```
const CarSchema= new Schema({
    Category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    CarName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Comment: Would be great if you can show the code you were working on. That way, it will be easier to help you.

Comment: please go through the code